# Lazy loading compound components typescript warning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, loading, lazy-evaluation

I have problem with typescript when I'm having an lazy loaded compound component

Compound Component

```
export default function A({
  children
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <div
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

A.component = SomeComponent;
```

Typescript warning: `Property 'component' does not exist on type 'LazyExoticComponent<typeof A>'.`

```
const A = lazy(() => import('./compoundComponent'));
<A>
  <A.component />
</A>
```

Typescript version: `5.3.2`

Comment: Do you mean it works fine without lazy loading?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi yes, just I'm not sure how to satisfy typescript